# How to properly load a set of images in python

Tags: python

I am trying to open a set of images in python, but I am a bit puzzled on how I should do that. I know how to do it with one image, but I don't have a clue on how to handle several hundreds of images.

I have a file folder with a few hundred .jpg images. I want to load them in a python program to do machine learning on them. How can I do this properly?

I don't have any code yet since I am already struggling with this.

But my Idea in pseudocode was

```
dataset = load(images)
do some manipulations on it
```

How I have done it before:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from numpy import genfromtxt,savetxt

load = lambda x: genfromtxt(open(x,"r"),delimiter = ",",dtype = "f8")[1:]
dataset = load("train.csv")
train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
test = load("test.csv")

linear = LinearSVC()
linear.fit(train,target)

savetxt("digit2.csv",linear.predict(test),delimiter = ",", fmt = "%d")
```

Which worked fine because of the format. Al the data was in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob) on python glob module and in a loop process each of the images in turn.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process each image individually (assuming you're using PIL or Pillow) then do so sequentially:

```
import os
from glob import glob

try:
    # PIL
    import Image
except ImportError:
    # Pillow
    from PIL import Image

def process_image(img_path):
    print "Processing image: %s" % img_path
    # Open the image
    img = Image.open(img_path)

    # Do your processing here
    print img.info

    # Not strictly necessary, but let's be explicit:
    # Close the image
    del img

images_dir = "/home/user/images"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # List all JPEG files in your directory
    images_list = glob(os.path.join(images_dir, "*.jpg"))

    for img_filename in images_list:
        img_path = os.path.join(images_dir, img_filename)
        process_image(img_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll look further in it